# Families of orthogonal curves to parabola.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, conic-sections, curves, parametric, curvilinear-coordinates

In a typical ODE course, we learn that families of orthogonal curves to parabola $y=Ax^2$ are given by families of ellipses, given by $x^2/2+y^2=c^2$. However, there is this thing called parabolic coordinates which are families of parabolas orthogonal to each other. It seems like either family of ellipses and another family of parabola can be orthogonal to families of parabolas. Can there exist more than one families of orthogonal curves?

Comment: What is "parabolic coordinates" ?

Comment: Of course. The orthogonality condition yields the tangent to a family of curves on the points of the single parabola only. Take a pencil and draw one yourself. Parabolic ccordinates $x=1/2 (\xi^2 -\eta^2), \  y= \xi \  \eta )$ are two families of mirrored parabolas with a common focal point intersecting family-wise eachother everywhere and form a conformal map (angle and area preserving locally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(see figure below).

No, (setting apart pathological cases) there is unicity of the family of orthogonal curves to a given family of curves depending on a parameter (in a differentiable way).

Indeed, in your case :

- the family of parabolas with equations $y=ax^2$ have the origin as a common **vertex**  whereas,
- the family of parabolas you mention (self orthogonal) with equations $y=-\frac{1}{2k}x^2+\frac{k}{2}$ have the origin as a common **focus** (blue for the initial family with $k>0$, red for the orthogonal family with $k<0$).

*Explanation for the second family :*

The directrix has equation $y=k$ ; expressing that the generic point $M=(x,y)$ must be at the same distance from the origin and from the directrix gives condition $x^2+y^2=(y-k)^2$. Expanding it, one obtains the given equation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! A parabola has the general form $y=ax^2+bx+c$, which has three parameters. The family of ellipsis are orthogonal to the case when $b=0, c=0$, whereas the the family of parabola are orthogonal to the case when $a=-\frac{1}{4c}$. Can we say that once we specified one the parameters, either $a, b$ or $ c$, there to exist an orthogonal families of curves to parabola corresponding to that parameter?

Comment: You have to fix $two$ parameters in order there is only one remaining. It is in the framework of a family of curves depending on a *single* parameter that the concept of orthogonal family makes sense.

Comment: For the complex interpretation, see for example [here](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/orthogonale/orthogonale.shtml)

Comment: Thanks for the information! Another question that came to my mind is that in $\mathbf{R}^2$, given a family of orthogonal trajectories, do they always form a coordinate system? If not, what are the conditions that they have to satisfy?

Comment: Good question. I am going to think about it before saying "yes" too quickly.